# remove all <div> , when ids are in matching some pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

All divs are inside of div `#main`
I have tree like structure of lots of divs.But divs are not child of other div, that is only connected with one line, all divs are generating at run time and for generating ID of any div, I am following a pattern like id of first child node= id of parent node+"1" and id of second child node= id of parent node+"2"

```
id of root div is node
id of first child node is node1
id of second child node is node2
id of first child of node1 is node11
id of second child of node1 is node12
id of first child of node11 is node111
id of second child of node11 is node112
...
...
...
```

Requirement: If I click on any div, then all child nodes till leaf should be deleted.

Comment: Take your time and explain it clearly.. and also post the code which you had tried.

Comment: How about using classes?

Comment: I have tried each function of jquery, which is not working

Comment: I can  post all code tommorow from office not now.

Comment: @tymeJV I did not use class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [starts with attribute selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to get the child elements that have ids which starts with `id` of the parent.

```
$('#main div').click(function(){
    $('[id^='+this.id + ']').remove();
});
```

Comment: there is any way, if i am using pattern matching?

Comment: I think simple starts with pattern is enough here.

Comment: @NikhilMishra It seems there is no need to care about pattern matching here.. check tymeJV's answer.

Comment: @Mr_Green I just asked for future reference

Comment: @NikhilMishra for future reference, store the `this` object in a variable. Still I think tymeJV's solution is valid in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear all child div's, you can do something along the lines of:

```
$("#node div").click(function() {
    $(this).children().remove();
});
```

Comment: children will not work because divs are not child, all node divs are individual.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(this).children('[id^='+this.id + ']').remove();
```